# How do I import a variable when defined in a method

Tags: python-2.7

My simple code works like this:

In `my_stuffmodule1.py`, I have the following:

```
import sys

def main():

    result = 'found stuff here'
    return result

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I want to use the result returned from `my_stuffmodule1` in my next module below, called `my_stuffmodule2`:

```
import my_stuffmodule1

result    
class Use_stuff(object):
    def stuff1(self):
        for item in result:
            code..
    def stuff2(self):
        code...
```

BUT I get errors such as 'result is not defined'. I want to use the items in the result string in `my_stuffmodule2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `result` is defined in `my_stuffmodule1.main`, it is only visible inside `main()`, once you call `main()`, it will be returned.

So in your second module, you need to do this:

```
import my_stuffmodule1

result = my_stuffmodule1.main()
```

Now you'll have the value of result in your second module. If you don't want to do this, then in your first module, you need to make sure `main()` is called when the module is evaluated (when its imported). To do that, you'll need to put a call to main in the global scope, like this:

```
def main():
    return 'result found here'

result = main()
```

Now, when you import the module, main() will be called and you can do this:

```
import my_stuffmodule1

result = my_stuffmodule1.result
```

Note that you still have to use `my_stuffmodule1.result` because you are importing the module directly. If you just want to have `result` shown, you could do this:

```
from my_stuffmodule1 import result
```

However, keep in mind that this will overwrite any other `result` you might have in your second module. Therefore, its better to import the module, then qualify the name with `my_stuffmodule1.result`.

Answer (score 0):

At a guess, I'd say it's because you're importing the first file, and the result string is only getting set when it's run in the context of 'main'. Also, you are returning the result variable - that variable is being defined within the scope of the main() function, and not in a 'global' scope, as it were.

If you were to simply set the variable result outside of the main() function, does that work?

Alternatively, set the value of result to the return value of the main() function, in the second script.

Below is a working example of the second option..

**my_stuffmodule1**

```
import sys

def main():

    result = 'found stuff here'
    return result

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**my_stuffmodule2**

```
import my_stuffmodule1

result = my_stuffmodule1.main() 
class Use_stuff(object):
    def stuff1(self):
        for item in result:
            code..
    def stuff2(self):
        code...
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want the `result` from the `main` method of `my_stuffmodule1` then you will need to execute that modules main method, in this case.

for example

```
import my_stuffmodule1

result = my_stuffmodule1.main()
class Use_stuff(object):
    def stuff1(self):
        for item in result:
            code..
    def stuff2(self):
        code...
```